# What's the difference between the Subdivision Surface modifier and the edit mode->RMB->Subdivide option?

Tags: subdivision-surface

Sorry for the newbie question.

I'm following the famous donut tutorial for blender 2.8.

When I press the apply button for the subdivision surface modifier to the torus it makes more vertices + faces for the donut. However, when I press the subdivide option after selecting all vertices of the donut in edit mode, it seems like it's also making more vertices + faces for the donut.

Are these two options interchangeable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello :). When the modifier is set to *Simple*, they are indeed interchangeable. The modifier also offers *Catmull-Clark* subdivision which works differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Modifiers are automatic operations that affect an object’s geometry in a non-destructive way. With modifiers, you can perform many effects automatically that would otherwise be too tedious to do manually (such as subdivision surfaces) and without affecting the base geometry of your object."
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html

If you want to preserve the mesh for ease of use, Modifiers are the way to go. if you don't care about it they are not that different except more options before applying the modifier

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer!
Subdividing is a destructive work flow. Which means u cannot undo what is done.
Whereas in subdivision surface modifier, it gives us liberty to undo, redo, increase or decrease subdivision.
I prefer using modifier. It makes the life lot simpler.